# Developing an OpenCV (Java) project in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, android-studio

I'm developing an Android (Kitkat) Application using the OpenCV Android SDK project.
But there is no document about using the OpenCV Android SDK in Android Studio. How do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool)

Comment: Me hope using Android Studio GUI step.

Answer (score 1):

This report is me result of trial and error.

Me Japanese only, sorry it English report mistake.

This report Japanese and English and Screen Capture version. => http://d.hatena.ne.jp/eryngii_mori/20140201/1391261653

1.Project window ”File" => "Project Structure…”

2.Project Structure window "Modules" => "+" => "Import Module”

3."Select File or Directory to Import" by Window. ZIP thaw OpenCV Library "OpenCV2.?.?-android-sdk/sdk/java" is select.( /sdk/java is Android library project )

4.module import is “sdk” => “Android”. select "Library module" check.

so far step is identical with Eclipse of “is Library” completed.

5.OpenCV importing your project select. “Dependencies”tab click, window under “Module Dependency…” click.

6.”Choose Modules”window is project of library ( image is “sdk” ) selected, “OK” click complete.

Your project Development of Android applications using the OpenCV(Java).