# org.opencv imports okay, but not org.opencv.android?

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, android-studio

I've followed [these instructions for adding OpenCV to a gradle project](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600674/319618), and it seemed to go okay, however in my source I can't import the OpenCV classes.

`org.opencv` seems to import ok, but not any of the sub-packages or classes. In Android Studio it looks like this:

[image]

As I type out the package name, after `org.opencv.` the only suggestion is `*`.

What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: You could try to "Sync Project with Gradle Files" (-> Tools -> Android), or reimport your project, or you can try to open your project by selecting the `settings.gradle` file in the root directory of your project.

Comment: Have you tried sync project with gradle using button available in tool bar.

Comment: So I actually made it a module in Android Studio and rebuilt the project, that seems to have fixed it.

Comment: If anyone else is seeing this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols may help.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue with Android Studio a couple of times

I find it is resolved by closing and reopening the project when the project reloads it has worked.

If that does not work try close and reopen Android studio.

The third thing you could try is |File|Invalidate Cache Restart| .