# Why can't I import the "common" part of Play Services com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker

Tags: android, google-play-services, accountpicker

I am trying to import Google Play Services in order to use the AccountPicker.
I followed the instructions, installed everything:

[image]

I also imported Play Services in my build.gradle file:

[image]

But the result is that I can definitely import com.google.android.gms but not com.google.android.gms.common
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html

[image]

I already tried to clean, rebuild,sync with Gradle, and delete the build folder.

Any idea what's going wrong?

Comment: Is 4.0.30 the latest version number? It shows exactly that line on the setup page, but it also says to make sure to update the number when necessary. Maybe they didn't update it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making Google Play Services 4.0.30 work with Android Studio 0.4.2 & Gradle 0.7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21103163/making-google-play-services-4-0-30-work-with-android-studio-0-4-2-gradle-0-7)