# AAR dependency in Android Library Project

Tags: android, gradle

My project has such structure:

- App1 (Android Application)
- App2 (Android Application)
- Common (Android Library)

I'm trying to use AAR dependency in Common:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
  ...
}
```

GooglePlayServices downloads and appears in build folder — https://cloudup.com/cAHR0ZrM09a, looks OK, but its classes are invisible during the build, and it fails with "cannot find symbol" error. For example, "cannot find symbol DetectedActivity", where DetectedActivity is using inside Common sources.

Is it possible to have AAR dependency in Android Library Project?

My goals are:

1. Described above project structure (App1 and App2 need to reuse Common codebase)
2. Common Library Project need to include AAR dependencies.

Build environment:
Android Studio = 0.4.2
OS = OS X Mavericks = 10.9.1
(project was created in 0.4.2)

Thanks!

Comment: There is a bug on dependency on 0.4.2.
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=64508

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio 0.4.2 suddenly cannot resolve symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols)

Comment: Works OK without any workarounds in 0.4.3.