# Update Android Studio Gradle plugin for new GDK release

Tags: gradle, android-studio, apk, google-glass, google-gdk

I wrote some cool Glassware with the first GDK release, but the application was broken by subsequent XE and over-the-air releases.

I updated the broken methods with new ones, but they are undefined.

How do I fix this?

Comment: There is an issue in android studio for dependencies check this if it can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols the issue is resolved for next release that is (0.4.3).

Comment: I resolved it with a series of updates and configs. See below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the steps that fixed the problem!

1. Go to Android SDK manager and get the latest GDK version under

   - Android 4.0.3 (this might change in the future, so scan or search)
   - GDK Sneak Peak
   - Install
   - Accept
2. Make sure Android Studio is up to date
3. Check gradle plug-in version .8->.9 (may be optional, brittle)
4. Fix the red squiggles (could be updating broken methods, for example)