# issue with actionbarpull's gradle file

Tags: java, android, android-gradle-plugin

I have some `build.gradle` file this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

that throws this error :

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'NewsFeeder'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_DebugCompile'.
      > Could not find any version that matches com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+.
        Required by:
            :NewsFeeder:unspecified
```

But, this reference to `chrisbanes's actionbarpulltorefresh`  seems to be correct : `https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/wiki/QuickStart-Stock`. How can it be since in this project is available in `[maven central repo][1]` ?

For information, I set in some `local.properties`file `sdk.dir=/home/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522/sdk`, which is the same that what `echo $ANDROID_SDK` returns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell gradle where it can look to find the dependency.  If you want gradle to use the mavenCentral repository then add this to your build.gradle file:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

The buildscript repositories is just for the build script dependencies, not project dependencies.  You want to add the repositories entry at the outer most, or project, level.

Your build.gradle would look like:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion '18'

    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion 18
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But it is put on the top of the file. Should I wrap it there ?

Comment: Put another repositories entry right above the dependencies entry.  See http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html

Comment: Now, everything works perfectly, but I can't access any class from the `actionbarpulltorefresh` project. Indeed, `import uk.co.senab.actionbarpulltorefresh.library.PullToRefreshLayout;` is not recognized. How can I handle this ? Where the `actionbarpulltorefresh` files are stored ?

Comment: Is not recognized in the IDE that you are using or not recognized when doing a build at the command line?  Gradle caches stuff in .gradle/caches/ in your home directory.

Comment: ..."Is not recognized by the IDE". In fact I don't have any `caches` directory in my `.gradle` directory.

Comment: You may be running into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896

Comment: @user1611830 Can you access the class in the library finally?