# With 0.4.3 Android Studio, error: "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly"

Tags: android, ide, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have noticed that several people are having issues after upgrading to Android Studio 0.4.3 (problem with 0.4.2 also I believe). My error and debug steps so far are as follows:

The message I see is "Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work properly" as shown in snapshot below.

[image: Error in Android Studio]

I found [this thread](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65219) and following instructions, but I still have the error. I am not able to do the following instruction in the thread:
**I went into Gradle settings and clicked on "use local Gradle distribution" and pointed it to*:
C:/Users/robot_000/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.10-all/6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12/gradle-1.10**

Do I need to have a local distribution of gradle? Where do I download it from and where do i put it? How do I now tell Android Studio to use it? (as you can tell, I don't understand how gradle works). Thanks for any help.

**Update 1**:
I found the gradle files on my computer at C:\Users\home.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-1.10-all\6vpvhqu0efs1fqmqr2decq1v12\gradle-1.10, but how do I do do this: "went into Gradle settings and clicked on "use local Gradle distribution" and pointed it to*" (as per [THIS THREAD](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=65219))

Answer (score 12):

Go to File > Settings > Gradle you will end up with this screen for setting up your gradle :

[image: gradle setting]

Also make sure you have Google Repository in your Android SDK directory which will be located at :

```
$SDK_DIR\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\3.1.36
```

If not do install it from SDK Manager > Extras > Google Repository first.

**EDIT :**

All your `build.gradle`(If you are using root level `build.gradle` to define android gradle plugin version, check in that only) must point to `0.8` version(latest as of now) of android gradle plugin

```
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
 }
```

**UPDATED :**

Mapping is :

```
 | Android Gradle Plugin |  Gradle Version |
       0.7.+                     1.9
       0.8.+                     1.10
```

Comment: Thanks, i found the setting but it did not work. What I had to do was create a completely new project, and use the old files (manually copied) and then run the new project. Not a solution, but it's been a full day i struggled with this, so will give it a rest for now. thanks for the help.

Comment: Check my edit. After doing these all do sync your project with gradle. If it doesn;t solve your problem follow the steps mention here by Scott once http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896

Comment: Deleting the Idea project files and reimporting won't help with this error finding play services. Also, please don't set up a local Gradle distribution in the IDE and point it at something in your .gradle folder; that's a temp folder and it can go away. Using the wrapper is a better way to go than using a local distribution.

Comment: Also I had to change gradle version number to 1.10 in my gradle wrapper file

Comment: Yes, But Android Studio if now smart enough to give you an option for auto fix too while syncing with gradle.

Answer (score 4):

File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart

Works sometimes for this

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem and using local gradle distribution didn't work for me either. I ended up finding the solution here [Gradle DSL method not found: 'runProguard'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27078075/gradle-dsl-method-not-found-runproguard)

Anything above gradle version 0.14.0 has to use `minifyEnabled` instead of `runProguard` in your projects build.gradle file. Here is how it should look :

```
buildTypes {

    release {

        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
```

Hope this helps. Check out the link if you are still confused

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly for me. I was searching and searching for the solution, this was the fitting answer

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this problem and found I already had the location of Gradle set and already had the Google Repository installed as mentioned by pyus13.

My solution was switching Android SDK Build-tools to a previous version fixed the problem. The latest revision was 19.1, but updating to that broke the tool chain.

It could just be as simple as trying another Build-tools.

[image: SDK Platform-tools and SDK Build-tools]

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont know what worked for them but for me worked to add a little scripts to build.gradle.
DO note its important to put them at the top of the page (in build.gradle).

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.2'
}
}
```

THEN: in buildToolsVersion I  had a version 19.1.0 and there for I installed build-tools (SDK manager) version 19.1 & 19.
I uninstall other build-tools packetes, im not a fan of useless stuff.

And you should be good to go, hope it helps someone..

Answer (score 0):

In the scope of the project, in the gradle properties file, you should add :

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, I don't know what worked for them, but for me worked to add little scripts to `build.gradle`.

Do note that it's important to put them at the top of the page (in `build.gradle`).