# Gradle Sync wont finish after 0.4.6 upgrade

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

After I upgraded my Android Studio to 0.4.6, it seems to get stuck with Gradle Sync. The yellow ribbon is persistently present on the top that says "Gradle Project Synch in Progress". However, there is no indication of any process running from the bar at the bottom.

When I try to run my application, it fails with "Gradle Project Sync Failed. Please fix your project and try again" message that appears in a balloon. However, there are no more information.

I was working on this project successfully before I upgraded to 0.4.6. And since 0.4.6 was updated quickly (within 5 days) from 0.4.5 to fix some gradle related bug, I am starting to wonder if this is something new they introduced.

Comment: Check your Gradle console output and include in it question.

Comment: Hello,There is nothing in the Gradle console output. There is also no indication of any process running.

Comment: Can you please include the `gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties` and `build.gradle` files .

Comment: Check the setting once from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347704/with-0-4-3-android-studio-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionali/21348714#21348714

Comment: Anything in the event log?

Comment: gradle-wrapper properties:

#Tue Feb 25 22:29:48 SGT 2014
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.9-all.zip

Comment: Build.gradle is too long to attach here.

Answer (score 3):

I just encountered the same problem this afternoon. I'm running on IntelliJ IDEA, should be similar.

What I did is:

- remove local Gradle from the $PATH (I used to set GRADLE_HOME variable and it's a different version)
- in build.gradle, change the classpath to

> classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.10.+'

- click File > Invalidate Caches/Restart (you can also manually remove the cache at ~/Library/Caches/{yourIDEName} and restart the IDE)

After this, the "Gradle Project Sync in Progress..." disappear once completed the syncing and I'm able to run my project again.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue:

- sync message stuck
- can't build/rebuild (failed to sync message)
- settings.gradle file is empty - has content with external editor.

I've downloaded a cannery version 0.8.11 (problematic version 0.8.9) which fixed the issue (after reverting settings.gradle to the version control revision).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem

Was messing with .gradle code and removed `include ':app'` from **`settings.gradle`** on accident