# EpilepticApp(Android Application)

Tags: java, c#, android

I am using android studio 0.8.6
I have tried to import my existing project into android studio but I get this error after importing the project 'Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g. editing, debugging) will not work proprerly'.

Kindly guide me.

Comment: update your SDK version

Comment: all explained here in this post [Gradle][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21347704/with-0-4-3-android-studio-error-gradle-project-sync-failed-basic-functionali