# Android Studio: Failed to sync Gradle project 'Project Name'

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I'm an android developer. Now I switched to Android Studio. While importing Android Eclipse project to Android Studio it gives an error like **Failed to sync Gradle project 'Project Name'**. I tried a lot to solve this error, even I changed Gradle path too. But still an error remains.

Comment: Did you [try this ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21996772/2591002) Try *deleting gradle and .gradle folders from your project folder*

Comment: Ya i followed all steps is in link @SweetWisher

Comment: It gives error like failed to find target  android -20

Comment: what is your min SDK ?

Comment: in eclipse i set it to 11 but in android studio i unable to find. I'm importing project to android studio.

Comment: Check [build.gradle (module:app)](http://i.gyazo.com/2b7b9c83a9bec2ab1812fcd43833b935.png)

Comment: after importing it says:- 'Gradle project sync failed. Basic functionality (e.g editing, debugging) will not work properly '

Comment: Check [classpath in build.gradle of your project](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27517208/2591002)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68024/discussion-between-sweetwisher--and-sushant-jamdade).

Comment: wait 5 min i ll check it out @ SweetWisher

Answer (score 1):

> failed to find target android -20

It seems that you haven't installed API 20 in your SDK manager. First check it and download if it's missing.

Then try adding this line `distributionUrl /gradle-2.2.1-all.zip to gradle-1.10-all.zip` in `gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties` like :

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=http\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip
```

Lastly, run Android Studio as Admin and clean the project :)

Hope it helps ツ

Answer (score 0):

Go to Gradle Tasks (tab on left), or type commands in terminal:

Run Clean and Build from Gradle Tasks, or you type in terminal: "gradlew clean" and "gradlew build" (without "").

Then go to Messages (there's tab down), and look what errors are reported. Try to solve it, or ask for help here.

Edit: To add, very likely problem with dependecies when importing eclipse project.