# Gradle project in Android Studio not importing libraries

Tags: java, gradle, android-studio

So I downloaded a template from http://www.androidbootstrap.com/ and I was  able to compile and deploy it after changing a few things. However, there are errors in every java and layout file. All of the libraries are showing up with red underlines in the imports section and all of their functions are doing the same. It's not able to find the functions when I'm editing, but when building it seems to be fine. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: It was a bug in AS 0.4.2 which is solved with release 0.4.3 . Upgrde your As to 0.4.3 .

Comment: I have the latest version as of this post.

Comment: you can try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896

Comment: After changing anything in your build.gradle files, you need to click on the Sync Project with Gradle Files button; have you tried that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of these solutions helped me solve my problem. I ended up creating a new project and giving up on Android Bootstrap because I could never get it to work. Things I do now to ensure gradle behaves well:

1. Updated Android Studio via the help menu. The latest version downloaded from Google was actually 0.4.2, and I was able to upgrade to 0.4.4.
2. Created a new project, without much fluff.
3. Made sure I could build the project and deploy.
4. When I added libraries, such as androidannotations, I added them to the second level gradle.build file and then immediately went to **tools-->refresh project from gradle**. Then I made sure the project built. This is important because your project won't import the library until you refresh the project from gradle.

Hopefully this helps some people who are getting into gradle development.

Answer (score 2):

Caches files must be corrupted.

Go to menu `File` and select `Invalidate Caches / Restart`

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case the solution was that I had to add `maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }` in `settings.gradle`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Wow! was skeptical but this really worked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Android Studio, so I can't say for sure. However, I do use its cousin IntelliJ. It sounds like Studio doesn't know about your Gradle build file. In IntelliJ, the Gradle plugin needs to be installed, and you need to add the build file to the project (or create a new project from an existing file). I would think those would be automatic in Studio. Regardless, try to see if something comparable applies for you.