# Adding a jar library for Android project in Android Studio 0.4.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I'm a newbie to **Android Studio** IDE. I used to implement Android application, using Eclipse IDE. As a beginner in Android Studio, I tried [this lesson from YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fHEvI_G6UtI) to include a external ***jar*** file to my project and use it. But unfortunately I'm unable to use that library even though the Gradle or Android build doesn't throw any error/exception when compile and run.

I've seen related questions from SO too. As an example, I've tried out things that discuss in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608135/android-studio-add-jar-as-library).

In the build.gradle file, I used

```
compile files('libs/jsoup-1.7.3.jar')
```

and next time used

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Neither work for me. After editing that ***build.gradle*** file, I used *Sync Project With Gradle* Files tools and also command line clean

```
gradlew clean
```

too. No error/exceptions, but when I try to write *Docu...* in my MainActivity class it doesn't show the import option *org.jsoup.nodes*, but show other imports options. What could be the mistake I've done.

Comment: Where did you put the libs folder?

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti parallel to src folder of my module

Comment: There were some bug in 0.4.2 related to dependencies do upgrade your studio t0 0.4.3 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Studio 0.4.2 suddenly cannot resolve symbols](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols)

Comment: @pyus13 yes, you are correct. I've updated to 0.4.4 and now it is working.

Comment: Ok its a very small thing but I had put it as answer so that StackOverflow doesn't count it as unanswered .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some bug in **0.4.2** related to dependencies management, do upgrade your studio to **0.4.3** will solve your problem .