# Android studio cannot resolve symbol View

Tags: java, android-studio

i have this import statement `import android.view.View;` **but in the editor and only in the editor** View is highlighted in red and when i hover over it it state that `Cannot resolve symbol 'View'` i mean that i dont get an error during build neither in logcat and the app is running well.
also line 103 is underlined in red and when i hover on `JSONException e` it state `incompatible type required java.lang.throwable found org.json.JSONExeption`. and again no build error and no logcat error.
can you figure out the problem? what is the solution?

```
package com.example.control;


import android.R.string;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.content.Intent;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class Actsign extends AppCompatActivity implements AsyncResponse {

  String nameValue, prenameValue, emailValue, genderValue,passwordValue,cfirmpasswordValue;
  Button btnsign, btnback;
  RadioGroup rgender;
  RadioButton sgender;
  EditText name, prename, email,password,cfirmpassword;
  TextView debugtxt,alrtname,alrtprename,alrtemail,alrtpassword,resptxt;
  
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_actsign);
    
    name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtnom);
    prename = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtprename);
    email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtemail);
    password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtpassword);
    cfirmpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtcfirmpassword);
    rgender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.rggender);
    btnsign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnconfirm);
    btnback = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnback);

    resptxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    
    btnsign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View V) {

        nameValue = name.getText().toString();
        prenameValue = prename.getText().toString();
        emailValue = email.getText().toString();
        passwordValue = password.getText().toString();
        cfirmpasswordValue = cfirmpassword.getText().toString();
        sgender = (RadioButton) findViewById(rgender.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        genderValue = sgender.getText().toString();
        
        insertData();
      }
      
    });

    btnback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

      @Override
      public void onClick(View arg0) {
        openNewActivity();
      }

    });

  }

  public void insertData() {
    sendDataAsync sendPostReqAsyncTask = new sendDataAsync(nameValue, prenameValue, emailValue, genderValue,passwordValue,cfirmpasswordValue);
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.setDelegate(this);
    sendPostReqAsyncTask.execute();
  }

  public void openNewActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Actlogin.class);
    startActivity(intent);
  }

  @Override
  public void processFinish(String output) {
    try {
      JSONObject resp = new JSONObject(output);
      boolean ok = (resp.getString("statue")=="success");
      if (ok){
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Actrealtime.class);
        startActivity(intent);
      }else
      {
        resptxt.setText(resp.getString("msg"));
        resptxt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If the code is building just fine, then it probably is a problem with the IDE. Have you tried refreshing the dependencies?

Comment: @m-alorda how to refresh dependencies. you mean synchronizing with gradle file? and yes the code is working and i still working on it but those errors i can say fake.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24971865/13688761) solve your problem?

Comment: @m-alorda thank you but tried all solution in this question and nothing worked i think i will just reinstall android studio.