# Cannot Resolve method Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-studio

How can I resolve this error? I am getting an error on this code:

> Cannot resolve method 'add(int, android.trey.startingpoint.nl.SecondActivity.PlaceHolderFragment)'

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

 public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Edit:Imports:

> import android.app.Activity;
> import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
>
> import android.os.Bundle; import android.view.LayoutInflater; import
> android.view.Menu; import android.view.MenuItem; import
> android.view.View; import android.view.ViewGroup; import
> android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng; import
> com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

Comment: cast PlaceholderFragment() to Fragment. ...and I believe you don't have two classes in the same .java file, do you?

Comment: Sorry i dont understand

Comment: is PlaceholderFragment a v4 SupportFragment?

Comment: can you show us the imports ? because you maybe using not the v4 fragment

Comment: Related post - [Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21100688/465053)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PlaceholderFragment might be a support fragment.

Change getFragmentManager to getSupportFragmentManager() as below:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
}
```

Your activity must also extend FragmentActivity.

Note:

If you don't intend on using support fragments then you can just change the import for the fragments.

Change import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; to import android.app.Fragment;

Comment: if that's the case fixing the imports will be easier for him

Comment: Yea i found out about this, but when i change that, i get an error saying Cannot Resolve method get supportFragmentManager,

And if i import the import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager; it just stays unused

Comment: @ImAtWar please you post your imports

Comment: edited.

But since this is a second Activity, i have more imports used in the main activity

Comment: change import android.support.v4.app.Fragment; to import android.app.Fragment;

Comment: Thx, it seems to work.. Tell me if im wrong, but is the Support an update for froyo? For older devices to work?

What if i wanted to use the support manager, what would be the solution?

Comment: in a way yes, the support library provides backward compatibility. If you wanted to use support manager then you would have to change getFragmentManager to getSupportFragmentManager

Comment: So if i use the Support Fragment, do i need an empty, private Fragmentmanager getSupportFragmentManager?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62120/discussion-between-androidenthusiast-and-imatwar).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
change getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
to 
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `import android.app.Fragment;` to `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

like

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        public PlaceholderFragment(){
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState){
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in your fragment file
using  `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`

rather than `import android.app.Fragment;`

than can fix it;

Here is example:

In your activity file:

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_set_travel_message);

    TravelMessageFragment fragment = new TravelMessageFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.travelInit,fragment).commit();

}
```

than in your fragment file:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class TravelMessageFragment extends Fragment{
private View view;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup group, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_travel_message, group, false);

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Cannot resolve method 'add(int, android.trey.startingpoint.nl.SecondActivity.PlaceHolderFragment)'

Change two things

First Thing :

you can create object of class "android.trey.startingpoint.nl.SecondActivity.PlaceHolderFragment" instead of putting class name

like

```
if(findViewById(R.id.fragment_container) != null) {

if(savedInstanceState != null) {

return;

}
PlaceHolderFragment mFragment = new PlaceHolderFragment();

mFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container,th
irdFragment).commit();

}
```

Second Thing:

Go to class file PlaceHolderFragment and change import " android.support.v4.app.Fragment" from "android.support.app.Fragment"

Answer (score -2):

Change `import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;` to `import android.app.Fragment;`

and also `getSupportFragmentManager()` to

```
getFragmentManager
    {
    if (savedInstanceState == null) 
        {
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
         }
```

it works for me