# Android Studio 0.9.0 - Cannot resolve symbols

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-support-library

After 6h spent trying to fix this by myself, AS is driving me crazy. Everything was fine yesterday and today it can't resolve any of the support libs nor the R symbols.

[image]

I tried everthing, including all the suggested fixes I found on StackOverflow. No need to tell me to have a look a [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols), I already have and none of the solutions work.

Here's what I tried so far :

- rebuilding / cleaning the project (many times...),
- synchronising the project with Gradle Files,
- check that the support lib is up-to-date in the SDK Manager,
- invalide Caches / restart AS,
- delete the .idea folder and the .iml files of my project, and re-importing it in AS,
- update AS from 0.8.11 to 0.9,
- eventually I ended up uninstalling AS and reinstalling it from scratch

And none of this fixed my issue...

Something really weird is that I also tried to create a whole new project from scratch and to copy/paste all my classes & resources from my corrupted project to this new one. And it worked for a while (~10 min), until it eventually became corrupted the same way, without any apparent reason.

Moreover, no idea if it's relevant, but when I type "ViewPager" in AndroidStudio and hit CTRL-SPACE, it doesn't suggest me the "android.support.v4.view.ViewPager" class. But if I hit CTRL-SPACE 3 times in a row, it DOES suggest it. So I guess that means that it's able to find the support lib somewhere but not to use it?

Here's my `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mathieumaree.library"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
}
```

Please, help me, otherwise I'm gonna break my computer soon.

Thanks in advance,

Mathieu

**EDIT 1 :**

I forgot to mention that this occurs only in one of my projects. The others seem to be fine (at least for now).

**EDIT 2 :**

I also forgot to mention that my project is composed of an application project plus a library module inside it. So here is the app's `build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mathieumaree.materialheaderviewpager"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile project(':library')
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.0'
}
```

The app Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mathieumaree.materialheaderviewpager" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name="com.mathieumaree.materialheaderviewpager.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

The library manifest :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mathieumaree.library">

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    </application>

</manifest>
```

The main `settings.gradle` :

```
include ':app', ':library'
```

And the main `build.gradle` :

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.14.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**EDIT 3 :**

After trying once more to delete all .idea folers & *.iml files and reloading my project, I noticed that AndroidStudio displayed an error at openning :

> Accessing invalid virtual file:
>   file://C:/Users/Mathieu/AppData/Local/Android/android-studio1/sdk/sources/android-21;
>   original:582; found:-: Accessing invalid virtual file:
>   file://C:/Users/Mathieu/AppData/Local/Android/android-studio1/sdk/sources/android-21;
>   original:582; found:-

I'm pretty sure it means it's looking for the SDK to yet another location (AppData/Local...android-21). What I don't understand is :

- there's no SDK folder at this location
- the SDK path indicated in the Project Structure is not this one

Any idea what all this means?

Comment: Seems like you've tried all the obvious things. Where is your SDK folder located?

Comment: It used to be in my C:/Program Files/Android/AndroidStudio folder. Then this issue appeared, I upgraded AndroidStudio and had to move my SDK to ~/MyAndroidStudioFolder/SDK (I just followed [this official blog post](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio0814inbetachannel))

Comment: If you click File -> Project Structure, is the path to your SDK shown there correct? (I doubt this is the issue, but best to check.)

Comment: Just checked, it's the right path :(. Don't know if you saw my edit, but I only have this issue on one project, the others seem to be just fine...

Comment: Yep, saw that. Did you bump the gradle plugin version when you upgraded AS to 0.9? Again, probably not the issue if other projects are fine...

Comment: Mmmh I'm not sure about that, what do you mean by "bump" ? If you mean upgrade the gradle version, I have no idea... I guess I'm using the 0.14.0 as stated in the build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, still not a clue what caused this problem but it would look like I managed to get rid of it, although I had to create a new project from scratch. What I really don't understand is that I've already done this yesterday and it didn't work out.

Comment: How u get rid of this project i also tried everything and now i am completely dumb

Answer (score 2):

try addind this to buid.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0
```

and change build tools version to 20.0.0

Also create a whole new project and see if the same errors are still present in that project.

Try "Tools" -> "Android" -> "Sync Project with Gradle Files"

Comment: The thing is, I want to use the support-v13, not the support-v4 lib. Plus, it was working 12 hours ago without the v4

Comment: try creating a whole new project and see if the same error occurs on that project

Comment: As described in my question, I've already done that... It worked fine for a few minutes and eventually ended up not working any more.

Comment: u havnt mentioned about createing new project. (i m not talking about re-importing the same project, but creating another sample project). anyways update ur question with all xml files u have. (manifest file more importantly) bcoz this r errors are mostly due to xml files

Comment: No offense, but yes I did : "Something really weird is that I also tried to create a whole new project from scratch and to copy/paste all my classes & resources from my corrupted project to this new one. And it worked for a while (~10 min), until it eventually became corrupted the same way, without any apparent reason."
Don't get me wrong, I'm grateful to you for trying to help!

Comment: check ur xml files... (upload them)