# Build of Wikipedia Android app fails

Tags: android, wikipedia, wikimedia

these days i tried to build mediaWiki's android platform follow the steps in readMe in  https://github.com/wikimedia/apps-android-wikipedia. 
But i got problems in android studio 1.0.1:

**problem 1:** **gradle project sync failed .Basic functionality will not work properly;**

i have tried advice from here [Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols/21100896#21100896) ,but could not figured it out.

**problem 2:** Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':wikipedia'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':wikipedia:_releasesprodDebugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve org.mediawiki.api:json:1.3.0.
>        Required by:androidWikipedia:wikipedia:unspecified
>   Could not GET 'https://tools.wmflabs.org/android-maven-repo/org/mediawiki/api/json/1.3.0/json-1.3.0.pom'. Received status code 503 from server: Service Temporarily Unavailable

problem 2 seems couldn't find org.mediawiki.api:json:1.3.0 from server.does anyone know where i can get that package ?

in addition,i'm novice of mediawiki_mobile , and met some problems i can't deal with , i wonder is there some website for mediawiki_mobile like stackoverflow i can discuss with other peopel ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think both problems are related. Please try again. This was a temporary issue (503), and has been fixed by restarting the web server.

If it still doesn't work, you might want to refresh Gradle dependencies:
./gradlew --refresh-dependencies

or remove
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.mediawiki.api/json/1.3.0

You can find the contact info for the mobile teams on https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Wikimedia_mobile_engineering#Contact_us.
Join the IRC channel and mailing list to better interact with the mobile team. Those are for both the mobile web and the mobile apps teams.

Comment: it's help. I tried import the project again and it run successfull. this time i use this git address [link](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/admin/projects/apps/android/wikipedia).and i can run the project on my phone. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The contents of the gerrit repo get copied over to the Github repo automatically. So, theoretically you should be able to build with either. The Gerrit repo is preferred though since it's the source repo and the best way to contribute patches back to the app.