# Errors while importing projects to android studio

Tags: android, eclipse, import, android-studio, project

While importing projects(project was created in eclipse) into Android Studio I have some problem:
1) R.file and methods are cannot be resolved

2) `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\StormY\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\21.1.2\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   Error:(153, 28) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'value' with value '@integer/google_play_services_version').`

Why did this happen? 
How can I fix this?

Comment: you need to include compile information for google play services

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the play_services_lib project into your workspace. And then add this library to you project by going to

Your Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library

Checkout this link for detailed explanation on how to import the play_services_lib into your workspace

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html

After this the error will vanish and you need not add any fixed value.

Comment: it helped thanks, but metods still unresolved, and I do not understand why

Answer (score 1):

According to the log, you are missing the google play services module.

Using google play services is different between eclipse and android studio. in eclipse you had to create a module and add a dependency on it. in android studio this is no longer needed. you should:
a) remove the google play services module from your project if it has been imported with it.

b) Add a gradle dependency on the current play services version ([see the docs for step by step instructions](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup)).

c) Make sure you Sync Project with Gradle Files (step 3 in the above link).

This should import google play services correctly which means your project would find google_play_services_version and compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the android repository, the support library like Google play services in your gradle for app module this dependency:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
```

prior to this you have use eclipse in which you included libraries by importing them in eclipse but in android studio you have to mention them in `build.gradle`  and after that you have to sync your gradle

like this [image]

this is the place where you will find app.gradle i have highlighted the file which you need to edit 
[image]

Comment: ye ty it works, but now as i said from beginning all metods is unresolved? for example :  
  
Error:(15, 2) error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
Error:(3, 60) error: package com.google.android.vending.expansion.downloader.impl does not exist
Error:(27, 61) error: package com.android.vending.expansion.zipfile.ZipResourceFile does not exist
 does not exist
Error:(5, 45) error: cannot find symbol class DownloaderService
Error:(65, 5) error: cannot find symbol class LicenseChecker

Comment: well this happens sometime if android studio can't make you difference between gen and src directories, check in your module what it has taken as source

Comment: can you specify how to do it?

Comment: btw I am very grateful that you are helping me

Comment: can't get all details but this should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-0-4-2-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols

Comment: in some cases which likely to happen here, if android studio encounters error it might not generate and resource related data just like eclipse. you can work way around by making a new android studio project and adding all libraries you need in "app.gradle"  and then port your classes on after another

Comment: nothing from links did not help (
sorry for wasting ur time, but i cant find app.gradle in my project

Comment: @Stormy, it's ok, i have updated the answer you will find app.gradle file in that i have highlighted that in image

Comment: still nothing, ill try to make new project and add lib, and  copy and paste clases, but still same- unresolved metods

Comment: @Stormy, mail me screenshot, to see how it looks, i might be able to look up something pankaj.nimgade@gmail.com

Comment: @Stormy, how many library did you need in eclipse when your code was working on eclipse apart from Google play service