# Android Studio, Cannot import anything

Tags: android, android-studio

I have no idea what is going on.  I'm using Android Studio and i've created a new Blank Project.

I type import an and the only thing that shows up in `Annotation` if i try to edit the existing 4 imports, it turns red and then switches everything back to those 4.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

I have no clue whats going on.

[image]

Comment: rebuild your project and see again.

Comment: @Nilesh it's a brand new project!

Comment: @Mike Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for late answer.

I solved this problem using **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

Go to **File** > **Invalidate Caches/Restart**.

The dialog will display and again select `Invalidate Caches/Restart`.

Answer (score 0):

You've provided very little information, but my guess is that your IDE is not locating your Android SDK.

Please make sure that everything is [configured correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18409923/606351). If it is, I suggest either providing more information (did your environment ever work properly? What are the changes?), or reinstall the IDE.

Comment: Vaiden - yes everything worked correctly up till this morning.  I havent changed any configuration

Comment: Vaiden - I also followed your link everything is configured correctly.  Again, I havent changed any configuration

Comment: Then I suggest trying to create a new project, and if that doesn't help - reinstalling the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is the normal behavior.

For me, I tried to use Handler which strangely isn't automatically imported. 
So I typed *an* which returns only:

[image]

In fact typing *android* will not show any suggestion:

[image]

Only after I typed *android.* (with dot) then I begin to see android related packages.

[image]

But this is pointless because I don't know which package Handler is in. So in the end I have to look it up on internet and paste the whole thing manually.

Comment: Can't you just write `Handler` somewhere, and wait for AS to ask you `Import class...`? On OSX, you just put the cursor over the unimported class and go option-enter.

Comment: That's what I do to any other import but for Handler it just stayed there in red without any light bulb icon. Or maybe I didn't wait long enough.

Comment: @inmyth actually this is normal behavior when automatic import is checked, i figured it out.