# PC Restarted and now Android Studio cannot resolve Activity, Calendar, Intent etc

Tags: android, android-studio

I hadnt noticed that my laptop was going to shut down due to low battery.
While I was writing code in Android Studio laptop shut down.
When I restarted it and opened Android Studio
it cannot resolve almost anything - Activity, Intent, Calendar etc.

When I mark the unresolvable symbol and click Alt+Enter, the only suggestion I get is "Setup JDK":

[image]

I tried this: [Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols) but to no result.

What do I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably lost its mappings, or at worst case something was corrupted.

Try re-mapping, or use the same EXE you used to install android studio to do a repair install.

Comment: I went for the dumbest approach and uninstalled AndroidStudio, deleted its folders from My Documents and now Im installing it anew