# Android Studio Java classes dont seemed linked to layout files

Tags: java, android, xml, layout

I am having an issue where I can not link my layout files to my java classes. I am importing code that I know worked into another project, and I moved all the source code and its associated layout xml files to the other project. (copy and paste)

Is their a way to link them back>

Here is an example:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera_protocol_demo);
```

It can not resolve activity_camera_protocol_demo.

Is their a fix for this?

It also does this with text views and buttons ect that are on the layout file.

Comment: Try rebuilding or cleaning your project. You find these options under the Build option

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Build --> Rebuild Project`. It solved to me all the problems I had.

Comment: @johnjil Try also cleaning your project. `Build --> Clean Project`

Comment: yeah I did that as well. Is there a file that would like these together?

Comment: @johnjil What is exactly the error that it gives to you? That it doesn't recognise the R file?

Comment: cant resolve symbol: StartTakePhotoButton (its a button.)

Comment: @johnjil Look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols. Maybe it could solve your problem.

Comment: @johnjil And nothing changes?

Comment: no not at all. I think I might be missing a file somewhere

Comment: @johnjil Are you sure that the layout it's on the folder layouts?

Comment: yeah, I think this is pretty rare

Comment: @johnjil Yes, I never had seen this (with the solutions that I put above I could solve it). It is only with this layout or with all layouts that you have?