# 'Cannot resolve symbol' and 'No resource found that matches the given name' - not a duplicate

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, r.java-file

I opened my project in Android Studio yesterday and got red everywhere with 'Cannot resolve symbol' as the description. It was completely random as no changes had been made to either the project or AS since the last time I opened the project. I ended up updating Android Studio to 2.0 and trying a bunch of solutions I found online but nothing works.

Like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols) guy, I have already tried:

- Rebuilding the project
- Cleaning the project
- Syncing with Gradle Files
- Closing the Project, closing AS and relaunching / reopening
- File > Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Examining Lint, didn't see anything obvious
- Double checking all support libraries are up to date in the SDK manager
- Examining my Build.gradle, although no changes and it's the same as usual, the way it was working all the time.

I have also tried the following steps (from the accepted answer):

1. Exiting Android Studio
2. Backing up ymyour project
3. Deleting all the .iml files and the .idea folder
4. Relaunching Android Studio and reimporting project

I also tried:

- Removing the 'proguard' entry in build.gradle
- Changing to "Use default gradle wrapper" in preferences

Another solution is to move 'buildTypes' in build.gradle but 'buildTypes' is already at the bottom of the Android section

Don't mark this as a duplicate if the "duplicate" is someone who fixed the same problem by doing something that didn't fix my problem.

Here are some screenshots:

[image]

As you can see, the color 'white' *does* exist:

[image]

R errors everywhere as well:

[image]

These errors are everywhere too:

[image]

Why are there two `res` directories and why is the one with the necessary resources a sub-directory of the `java` directory? Could this be related? Screenshot here:

[image]

EDIT: I created a `drawable` directory in the main `res` directory and added one of the drawables that won't get picked up by build variants. It removed the relevant 'Cannot resolve symbol' error. But when I deleted the main `res` and tried try to move the whole res directory in the `java` subdirectory to the `main` directory I got the following error:

[image]

EDIT: I managed to build without errors by deleting the outer `res` directory, copying the one inside the `java` one, pasting that into the `main` directory then deleting the one inside the `java` directory. How these got moved around like that I do not know. Probably caused by following the 'solution' of deleting and importing the project again. Whether it actually runs properly on a device I do not know as Android Studio is hanging for the last 20-30 minutes (as it does sometimes). If it does I may answer my own question with what I did to finally fix the problem.

Comment: Show us what went wrong like put some screencasts (At what words you get this error. ??)

Comment: @Kathi I'll take a couple screenshots and edit my answer.

Comment: @Kathi I edited my answer with screenshots

Comment: Review your all XML files.

Comment: Make sure you have `color.xml` file in `res -> values` folder and it contains value with `Item Name White`. If not then add this.  And the problem is solved.

Comment: @ShreeKrishna What am I supposed to look for? Nothing changed since the last time I built it without error. All of the resources each layout points to exist for example.

Comment: @jaydroider White exists just like all the resources that are referenced but come up with red. I'll post a screenshot for proof.

Comment: @Questioner May be something changed after upgrading IDE. But I am mostly sure this problem always raises if there is something error in XML.

Comment: Whatever @ShreeKrishna is saying is right. I suggest you to `Recheck` all your XML Resources.

Comment: @Questioner The way you defined value for `Item Name White` is wrong. Try with `<resources>
    <color name="white">#FFFFFF</color> </resources>`. as i said in res -> values -> color.xml file.

Comment: Recheck all your xml, and make sure your compile version 23 because your using 23.0.2 build tools, alway try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: @jaydroider I cropped that color out after I took the screen. It is wrapped in a <resources> tag. I will change it to the <color> tag as you said and try again but I don't see how it built without errors for such a long time before I started getting this problem.

Comment: Could you please paste code blocks instead of screenshots for anything that doesn't require a visual? Such as the entire colors.xml file and the text of the error logs? Thanks

Comment: @cricket_007 Kathi asked me to provide screenshots at what words I get the error so I did.

Comment: @Kathi Yes, 23 and 23.0.2. That's already the case.

Comment: What about your dependencies ? all are 23. Also post some code, Gradle files and your files contain errors. so that we can figure out .

Comment: The errors seem to be at least partially related to build variants not being able to access main resources (that should be common to all variants). Why is this and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually solved it by moving (by copying, pasting and deleting since AS wouldn't let me move it) a `res` directory that had been misplaced from deleting and re-importing the project to try and fix it initially. I don't know which one of the solutions worked but one of them must have. I just had to fix my project again after the re-importing 'solution' broke it. The `res` directory was a sub-directory of `java` when it should have been one level up as a sub-directory of `main`.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows you that you do not have value `white` in `color` constants.
Please check all your resource files (`colors.xml`, `strings.xml` and so on) - do you have line
`<color name="white">#FFFFFF</color>` in one of them?

Comment: Nothing changed since before the error. Everything referenced everywhere exists. I posted a screenshot of the 'white' value in colors.xml. It's not the only example of this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a new project entirely, and copy and paste everything. XML files, classes, etc. That should solve your problem.