# Android Studio 2.3.1 cannot resolve symbol from imported module

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a project with a module,

I need to use my module to my project and I used : File > Invalidate Caches / Restart

But cannot resolve symbol its import...

My Android Studio version : 2.3.1

Comment: refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols

Comment: what have you tried so far. what exactly is the error can you post your log here or the exact error it is throwing ?

Comment: show us some efforts ,what you tried yet!

Comment: I tried Invalid Cache / Restart , Clean Project , I closed android studio and deleted .idea folder and iml files.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem first Invalidate Caches/Restart and closed Android Studio and deleted *.iml files and .idea folder then I added

```
    compile project(path: ':audiorecordlibrary');
```

To app dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Do with these may be it will work,

1.Right click the jar file in file tree within AS and select "Add as library..."

EDIT: You can do "File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart" option to fix this.

EDIT 2: This fix should work for all similar incidents and is not a twitter4j specific resolution.

1. It's a bug in Android Studio 2.2 Preview 1. It's reported here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210255

Comment: I tried your suggestions, but not working. My module is not Jar

Comment: Have you tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols