# Android Studio 3.1 Stable. Build Successful but Can Not Resolve Error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.1

I have updated to `Android Studio` 3.1 Stable Version today(27 March 2018).

I have an old project. With new studio version, it gets build successful and app gets installed on `Emulator`, but the on the `IDE`, Activity file shows

> Can Not resolver Error

.
[image]

gradle file app module

[image]

Project level gradle file

[image]

Comment: show the imports file in the file structure

Comment: try to run the project and see error goes or not?

Comment: Is there any error on logcat ?

Comment: @0xalihn no error. only warning like compile deprecated. i fixed them. and Build shows successful. see in first image.

Comment: @sayaMahi did you solve this issue,,,,???

Answer (score 8):

I spent a long time on this yesterday after migrating from Android Studio 2.3 to 3.1. Tried everything from other answers to similar questions. Google's maven repository was correctly configured, tried invalidating caches and restarting, restarted the computer, etc.

The one thing that worked for me was closing Android Studio, deleting the `.idea` folder from my root folder and starting Android Studio again. Since I had everything checked into git before starting the upgrade I was able to do:

```
rm -rf .idea/
git checkout .idea
```

So I ended up with my original idea project files, but you should be fine if you can't revert to your checked in idea files. After reopening Android Studio it recreated some of the files I ended up deleting and everything worked again. Hope that helps others with the same problem.

This answer is old but basically suggests the same thing so I guess this problem keeps showing up. https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100896/791560

Comment: So simple, yet so difficult to find when desperately trying!

Comment: Then do i need to delete .idea folder in every project?

Comment: I was having a similar problem (many errors in Android Studio, even though the app compiles and runs on phones just fine) and deleting the project's .idea/ folder fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to Fix:

https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies.html#google-maven

From Android Studio 3.1, if we are working on Old projects built on 3.0 or lower, you need to add maven repository at top level build.gradle file. i.e., add google() under repositories of all projects.

For new projects, it gets added automatically.

App level, build tools version should be at min 27.0.3

Make sure compilesdk version and support library version are the same version level.