# Cannot resolve symbol 'com' in android studio

Tags: android, react-native, android-studio

I'm doing google/facebook login in react native with firebase. When
i trying to open it in android studio and got this error in 3rd step of integrate firebase in android
[ref](https://aboutreact.com/integrate-firebase-in-android-and-ios-app/)

[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GpYmV.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio suddenly cannot resolve symbols](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols)

Comment: i have try but not work, when i open project structure Prem appear(1): Project PetShop: project SDK is not defined

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to use `react-native-firebase` SDK from [invertase](https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/quick-start/existing-project). This simplifies all the integrations.
I will narrow down the steps which are required to integrate firebase authentication to an existing react-native project for android.

- We can use yarn for installing react-native-firebase. Enter below commands one by one in the project directory.
  `yarn add @react-native-firebase/app`

  `yarn add @react-native-firebase/auth`

  `yarn install`
- Download the `google-services.json` file and paste it into `/android/app/`. (Your package name in `google-services.json` should be similar as the package name included in `android/app/src/main/java/com/(ProjectName)/MainApplication.java`
- Add the below line to `android/build.gradle` in `dependencies` as shown.
  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'`
  `dependencies {
      classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")
      classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
  }`
- Add the below line to the bottom of `android/app/build.gradle` file. 
  `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`

Now run the project and it should be working fine.

Comment: Thanks for help.sorry for late reply