# Does anyone know the usual reason for when layout attributes are not recognized by Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-build

Here's the sort of thing I'm experiencing:

[image: Layout attributes not recognized]

When I hover over any of the attributes like `android:id`, for example, I see the following:

```
Attribute android:id is not allowed here
```

I've tried cleaning the project, syncing the project with Gradle files, rebuilding the project, and lastly, invalidating caches and restarting. Yet, nothing I do seems to fix it.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:** Problem was solved by deleting, recloning, and rebuilding the project.

Comment: This seems related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21100688/android-studio-suddenly-cannot-resolve-symbols. Reading through that one now...

Comment: make sure your parent layout has `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`

Comment: Problem resolved. I deleted the entire project directory and cloned it again from the remote repo.