# Unsatified Link Error: Android OpenCV

Tags: java, android, eclipse, opencv

I followed this guide:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html

but am still getting this error:

E/AndroidRuntime(916): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java248 from loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.smartlab-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example.smartlab-2, /system/lib]]]: findLibrary returned null

When I call this line:

```
System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aren't you [following this tutorial instead?](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/desktop_java/java_dev_intro.html)

The one you linked does not have the line:

```
System.loadLibrary( Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME );
```

And it says:

> Note the call to System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME). This
>   command must be executed exactly once per Java process prior to using
>   any native OpenCV methods. If you don’t call it, you will get
>   UnsatisfiedLink errors. You will also get errors if you try to load
>   OpenCV when it has already been loaded