# How to package and link OpenCV binares and OpenCV Java SDK for Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, opencv, gradle, android-studio

Trying to get started with OpenCV Java SDK on Android Studio creating an app targetting 14 - 19.

I'm following steps defined by @Paito here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/20600674/1291489

1) I package libs in a .jar

[image]

2) Add dependencies:
    ...
    dependencies {

```
    //OpenCV
    compile files('libs/opencv-2.4.8.jar')
    compile project(':app:libs:opencv')
}
```

3) Copy the OpenCV java folder

[image]

4) Create and fix build.gradle for OpenCV (same as referenced source)

5) Try to use the library

```
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
...
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {}
```

Results:
    App builds and runs but I get the following exception:

```
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to get library list
03-19 19:54:46.144  E/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Library list: ""
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ First attempt to load libs
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to init OpenCV libs
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to load library opencv_java
03-19 19:54:46.144  D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Cannot load library "opencv_java"
03-19 19:54:46.154  W/System.err java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java: findLibrary returned null
```

**Not able to see what's wrong here. I tried every possible way of packaging the .jar file and repeated the steps at least 10 times with tweaks.**

I also tried structure:

```
-opencv.jar
  -libs
    -armeabi-v7a
      -(.so files)
```

I am testing on a Samsung GS3Mini and Genymotion 4.1.1, and getting same results on both. Both are running OpenCV Manager and samples.

Comment: Try my solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/22427267/1741671 , it will work and easy to understand

Comment: @TGMCians, I followed your instructions and got the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the *.so files in `/main/jniLibs` folder if your gradle plugin is 0.7.2+ and add the opencv java as library, follow the steps which I covered here.

[How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267)

Comment: This fixed it! For the sake of correctness the folder is (Project)/(APPModule)/src/main/jniLibs (as you mentioned in your previous answer) be nice if you could fix answer! Thank you @TGMCians!

Comment: The generated .apk is now 28MB where it was ~2 previously. Any ideas on which of these jniLibs to attach for a production release? Any of these not needed? Will target 4.0+ devices only.

Comment: You have to add them all for a production release also.

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned in the answer, but finally have the same issue - " Couldn't load opencv_java". Although in the root of my apk there is 'lib' folder with arm64-v8a, armeabi and others folders with libopencv_java3.so file. Could you please suggest what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So close, try this structure:

`-opencv.jar
  -lib
    -armeabi-v7a
      -(.so files)`

Android Studio:

[image]

Update: Looks like @TGMCians has a better solution for you with the new Gradle.

Comment: Thank you again. This approach didn't work for me in my first try :( EDIT: As said by @TGMCians above looks like it's a matter of versions with Gradle (will update answers and all when I confirm this).

Comment: It's not an issue with Gradle versions as I currently use 0.9.+; However I do like TGMCians solution better and will probably switch too it soon.