# Use NDK in Android Studio (OpenCV)

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, android-studio

I am trying to setup OpenCV in Android Studio, using NDK. The steps I have followed are:

1. Create a **library project** for *OpenCV* and import it in *MyProject*.
2. Add all OpenCV **library files** to the */jni* folder.
3. Create **Android.mk** file

However, when I run the Android.mk with **ndk-build** I get this error:

```
Nothing to be done for `.../MyProject/jni/Android.mk'.
```

This is the content of Android.mk:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

OPENCV_CAMERA_MODULES:=on
OPENCV_INSTALL_MODULES:=on

include /.../MyProject/jni/OpenCV.mk
```

I am stuck at building the libraries, any help?

---

**SOLUTION**

I managed to use NDK by linking gradle to an external installation of it, and by also using *javah* to created implementation headers for native methods.
Follow these steps to setup Gradle to use NDK:

- **install** ndk (it's not built into Android Studio, so it needs to be installed manually)
- setup ndk.dir in local.properties and ndkDir in gradle.properties to link to **installation path**
- create "**jni**" folder in src/main
- add **Application.mk** file to jni

  APP_ABI := armeabi
  APP_PLATFORM := android-9
- add **Android.mk** file to jni (change LOCAL_SRC_FILES and LOCAL_MODULE values)

  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)

  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.c
  LOCAL_LDLIBS += -llog
  LOCAL_MODULE := hello

  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
- add this code to gradle

  ```
      sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

      // take the built .so files and place them in jniLibs
      //noinspection GroovyAssignabilityCheck
      task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
          commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
                  'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
                  'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
                  'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
                  'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
      }

      tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
          compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
      }
  ```
- **setup javah** as External tool (point to your installation directory)
  Program: /usr/bin/javah
  Params: -v -jni -d $ModuleFileDir$/src/main/jni $FileClass$
  Working dir: $SourcepathEntry$
- **run javah** on .java file containing native method -> header is created
- create implementation file
- specifiy module in gradle:

  ```
  defaultConfig {
      minSdkVersion 9
      targetSdkVersion 21
      versionCode 4
      versionName '1.11'

      ndk {
          moduleName "hello"
      }
  }
  ```
- done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot yet use Android Studio for NDK development, but you can add pre-built *.so files of Open CV in your  project in the new version of Gradle 0.7.2+

Follow the steps here: [How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267)

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. After having added the module dependency following your instructions, I get this error when I sync gradle: Gradle 'Selfie-o-matic' project refresh failed: Configuration with name 'default' not found.
What could be the problem?

Comment: You need to make sure that each submodule in your project has its own build.gradle file.

Comment: I was using the wrong path, but now everything works fine. One last question, where do I need to place the haar cascade xml files?

Answer (score 4):

I have posted a new post about how to build an Android NDK application with OpenCV included
using Android Studio and Gradle. More information can be seen [here](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/), I have summarized two methods:

(1) run `ndk-build` within Gradle task

```
sourceSets.main.jni.srcDirs = []

task ndkBuild(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
    ndkDir = project.plugins.findPlugin('com.android.application').getNdkFolder()
    commandLine "$ndkDir/ndk-build",
            'NDK_PROJECT_PATH=build/intermediates/ndk',
            'NDK_LIBS_OUT=src/main/jniLibs',
            'APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=src/main/jni/Android.mk',
            'NDK_APPLICATION_MK=src/main/jni/Application.mk'
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    compileTask -> compileTask.dependsOn ndkBuild
}
```

(2) run `ndk-build` with an external tool

Parameters:  `NDK_PROJECT_PATH=$ModuleFileDir$/build/intermediates/ndk NDK_LIBS_OUT=$ModuleFileDir$/src/main/jniLibs NDK_APPLICATION_MK=$ModuleFileDir$/src/main/jni/Application.mk APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=$ModuleFileDir$/src/main/jni/Android.mk V=1`

More information can be seen [here](http://hujiaweibujidao.github.io/blog/2014/10/22/android-ndk-and-opencv-development-with-android-studio/)