# Couldn't load opencv_java249: findLibrary returned null - OpenCV in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to load the Open CV Library to my Android Studio application. I need to make the circle detection in my application.

I used this tutorial to load this library: 
[How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267)
(the last one one this page).

Before running my program everything looks right. But when I am trying to run it I have an error:

```
   06-11 14:48:02.010    1349-1349/com.example.teczowka.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load opencv_java249: findLibrary returned null
        at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:365)
        at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:535)
        at com.example.teczowka.app.MojHough.process(MojHough.java:23)
        at com.example.teczowka.app.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:98)
        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2534)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:372)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.superOnMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:244)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:164)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivity.java:130)
        at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivityDelegateICS$WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(ActionBarActivityDelegateICS.java:308)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.onMenuItemSelected(PhoneWindow.java:958)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:735)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:149)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:874)
        at com.android.internal.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.onItemClick(MenuPopupHelper.java:156)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1086)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2855)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3529)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I've tried almost everything and I have no idea what is going on. I've spent all day to figure it out - with no result. Can anyone help me ?

Here is my code:

```
  public Bitmap process(Bitmap src) {
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
    Mat imgSource = new Mat();
    Mat imgCirclesOut = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(src, imgSource);

    //grey opencv
    Imgproc.cvtColor(imgSource, imgSource, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(imgSource, imgSource, new Size(9, 9), 2, 2);
    Imgproc.HoughCircles(imgSource, imgCirclesOut, Imgproc.CV_HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, imgSource.rows() / 8, 200, 100, 0, 0);

    float circle[] = new float[3];

    for (int i = 0; i < imgCirclesOut.cols(); i++) {
        imgCirclesOut.get(0, i, circle);
        org.opencv.core.Point center = new org.opencv.core.Point();
        center.x = circle[0];
        center.y = circle[1];
        Core.circle(imgSource, center, (int) circle[2], new Scalar(255, 0, 0, 255), 4);
    }
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Utils.matToBitmap(imgSource, bmp);
    return bmp;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you to use [async initialization of OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-async-initialization) instead of [static initialization](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#application-development-with-async-initialization) which you are currently using.

Answer (score 2):

first of all try to load all your libraries in a static block

```
static{
    OpenCVLoader.initDebug();
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);
}
```

and also check your apk file to make sure that opencv libraries (*.so) are included in the apk. (try opening the apk with an archive viewer and look inside "libs" directory)

finally the library name is a little bit strange it usually is "libopencv_java.so" (for all opencv versions including 2.4.9) so I guess try loading that instead of Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME to see if anything happenes.

Comment: It's weird that the official Core.java returns `opencv_java249` for the Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME although the actual name is `opencv_java.so`. Anyhow, using `OpenCVLoader.initDebug()` should be enough - no need for `System.loadLibrary(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to add the Native Libraries to you project, the .so files.
You need add to \lib\ folder in your project the platforms folders in this path:
OpenCV-x.x.xx-android-sdk\sdk\native\libs\
 - armeabi
 - armeabi-v7a
 - mips
 - x86

Which folder you need add depends in what is your target architecture, and this is how i solved the problem you have.