# Importing OpenCV SDK in Android Studio

Tags: opencv, android-studio, android-library

I am new open to Android Studio.

I was trying to import the OpenCV SDK into Android Studio to be used as a library. 
This is not working.

I am using Android Studio 0.8.6 and OpenCV 2.4.9 versions.

Using Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

Please help me through this.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool - this answer might help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had got it all wrong! 
I had to download OpenCV for Android SDK which I had missed. Had downloaded OPENCV SDK.

It's working now.