# Live streaming video from mobile devices (iOS & Android) to server

Tags: android, ios, video, streaming, rtmp

I'm currently working on a project which requires video from Android and iOS devices to be streamed live to our server.

I've been researching this for a while, and come across libraries that are dead, expensive, or dead expensive.

The only viable solution I've found so far is using Adobe FlashBuilder, but it is quite frankly not very nice for multiple reasons.

I would love to be able to do this natively for both platforms, but this is not a very juicy project for my employers, so they are reluctant to spend any cash on expensive libraries.

Are there any free/cheap libraries that fit the bill? Is there some other way for me to do this natively? The technology itself is negotiable, we are currently focused on RTMP since we are using FlashBuilder, but as long as the video is streamed up to a server then they don't particularly care what protocol is used.

Thanks for your help in advance, let me know if the way I've asked this question is not up to scratch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can say about Android. I'm in my application using openCV library specifically FFmpegFrameRecorder can work with RTMP protocol. My application works with RED5 server. Of the drawbacks I would mention a large number of native libraries.

See my answer, I described there that I used
[Android Studio with javaCv and FFMPEG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27100226/android-studio-with-javacv-and-ffmpeg)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, unfortunately we need a solution that will work with both platforms. Perhaps FlashBuilder is really my only option.

Comment: but openCV worked on ios too, I just have not delved into the details