# OpenCV Service Intent must be explicit, Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, opencv, android-intent

I'm building this application for my bachelor's diploma that uses OpenCV. Everything was going fine until I updated my phone's Android to 5.0.

After the update my project stopped working, because of this:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }

I have read and informed myself about the new restrictions regarding implicit intents in Android 5.0, but how can I get around this in order for OpenCV to work?

I could modify the  **AsyncServiceHelper.java** file in the OpenCV SDK in order to try and fix this, but how could I get the Class object of the OpenCV service that needs to be run, in order to use an explicit intent?

Or maybe this approach is a dead end, but are there any other approaches to this, or are my only options either an update to the OpenCV SDK, or to downgrade the Android Version on my device?

Comment: Show us the code for bindService()

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I think changing the android:targetSdkVersion is not a solution for very long ;) So instead I added the package name to make the intent explicit:

```
public static boolean initOpenCV(String Version, final Context AppContext,
        final LoaderCallbackInterface Callback) {
    AsyncServiceHelper helper = new AsyncServiceHelper(Version, AppContext,
            Callback);
    Intent intent = new Intent("org.opencv.engine.BIND");
    intent.setPackage("org.opencv.engine");
    if (AppContext.bindService(intent, helper.mServiceConnection,
            Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        AppContext.unbindService(helper.mServiceConnection);
        InstallService(AppContext, Callback);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Maybe someone can tell an opencv comitter about this, to push a hotfix.

***EDIT:*** From a comment below: For anyone else wondering the location of this function, it's in src/main/java/org/opencv/android/AsyncServiceHelper.java

Comment: Yes, setPackageName() is the solution for the Lollipop error or starting Services.

Comment: Thank you Simon. For anyone else wondering the location of this function, it's in src/main/java/org/opencv/android/AsyncServiceHelper.java

Comment: Set this as the answer to the question, since it feels more like a solution and less as a workaround. Thanks! :) I'll also update my project with your solution

Comment: thanks for your solution, but somehow this doesn't work for me.. My application now keeps saying OpenCV Manager isn't installed, which is installed actually...

Comment: It is asking to install the OpenCV while it is a part of this project. Even if we install it from external source force close after that.

Comment: Amulator Android API23, solution didn't help

Answer (score 7):

I saw a answer here when at work, tested it and that solved the issue. Apparently it was deleted in the meanwhile. Posting it again for reference

The solution was changing: **android:targetSdkVersion** in the AndroidManifest.xml from **21** to **19**. Can't believe it was this easy and I lost a day trying to figure it out, buy hey, thanks again to the one who posted the initial answer :)

Thanks stackoverflow!

Comment: Well this is not a solution if you use some features of the 21 SDK…

Comment: Currently this is not a concern for me since I see it as a temporary solution anyway. I fully expect for the OpenCV guys to properly fix this. However its more important for me to go forward with the coding, and switch to a proper solution when one appears... However, you are right. This solution is not ideal, and should be viewed only as a temporary one

Comment: It is asking to install open CV. and even if we install it from external source force close after that :P

Comment: That's a hack, not a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed OpenCV version to 3.0 and the problem was solved:

**From**

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_3, this, mLoaderCallbck);
```

**To**

```
OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, mLoaderCallbck);
```

Answer (score -5):

In order to run application at any version of android i.e. latest version.

Remove tag - **android:targetSdkVersion**.

Comment: If (android:targetSdkVersion) not set, the default value equals that given to minSdkVersion. - from the android documentation page. This is not ideal..

Comment: No georgej, please try to remove the tag, it won't create any problem to any version.