# OpenCV library with android application

Tags: android, opencv

I am using OpenCV library in android application to recognize the vehicle plate text.

I have imported the opencv_library-2.4.3 jar file and imported the native libraries in armeabi and armeabi-v7a but when run my application, shows me this error

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service Intent must be
>   explicit: Intent { act=org.opencv.engine.BIND }

this is the line of code causes the error

```
 Boolean checkOpenCV =OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2,
                                             getApplicationContext(),
                                             mLoaderCallback);
```

I searched a lot about this issue but I couldn't find anything helpful!
Can anybody help me to resolve it?
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27470313/opencv-service-intent-must-be-explicit-android-5-0-lolipop

Comment: No, not duplicate. I saw this resolution before but my case is different.

Comment: Have you try with this `OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0` instead of `OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_2_4_2`.