# findLibrary returned null with OpenCV4Android in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, opencv, java-native-interface

I want to use OpenCV for the Android app I am currently working on, written in Java.

To setup OpenCV, I followed exactly the steps explained on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267) as well as on [this one](http://answers.opencv.org/question/14546/how-to-work-with-opencv4android-in-android-studio/) (tried both solutions without success). When I then let my project rebuild it works, but when I let my code run, it fails when trying to do the following:

```
fdetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
```

The error I get is `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.features2d.FeatureDetector.create_0:(I)J`, kind of the same as in [the aforementioned question page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267). I tried all solutions proposed on this page but none of them worked for me.

I do have installed JNI, so I guess this is not the problem. Or m
My setup is the following:

```
-app
    |-libs (with my other app libraries, including javacv.jar)
    |-src
         |-main
               |-java (with my code)
               |-res
               |-jniLibs (with the .so files from the OpenCV's sdk\native\libs\x86)
         |-build.gradle
-libs
     |-opencv
             |-build
             |-jniLibs (with the same .so files as I was not sure where to put them)
             |-res
             |-src
             |-build.gradle
```

My app's build.gradle contains the following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.java'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.so'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.2'
compile project(':libs:opencv')
}
```

And the opencv's build.gradle contains the following sourceSets:

```
sourceSets {
main {
  manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
  java.srcDirs = ['src']
  resources.srcDirs = ['src']
  res.srcDirs = ['res']
  aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
  jniLibs.srcDirs = ['jniLibs']
}
}
```

My settings.gradle contains an `include ':libs:opencv'`

I really cannot see where I did something wrong, can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can u try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/27356635/1180117 ? It is simpler.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you very much! Still not sure about what I did wrong but now it gets there. Remark that I followed the video that user G3M indicated as well (added the ndk.dir location to the local.properties)

Comment: Didn't it work with out ndk.dir location in local properties ? I never needed it.

Comment: I haven't tried yet without it, but I guess it would be fine as well if it works for you. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below steps for using Android OpenCV sdk in Android Studio.

1. **Download** latest OpenCV sdk for Android from [OpenCV.org][1]  and decompress the zip file.
2. **Import OpenCV to Android Studio**, From *File -> Import Module*, choose *sdk/java* folder in the unzipped opencv archive.
3. **Update build.gradle** under imported OpenCV module to update 4 fields to match your project build.gradle a) compileSdkVersion b) buildToolsVersion c) minSdkVersion and 4) targetSdkVersion.
4. **Add module dependency** by *Application -> Module Settings*, and select the *Dependencies* tab. Click *+* icon at bottom, choose *Module Dependency* and select the imported OpenCV module.
5. **Copy *libs*** folder under *sdk/native* to Android Studio under *app/src/main*.
6. In Android Studio, **rename the copied *libs* directory to *jniLibs*** and we are done.

Step (6) is since Android studio expects native libs in `app/src/main/jniLibs` instead of older `libs` folder. For those new to Android OpenCV, don't miss below steps

- include `static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); }`
- For step(5), if you ignore any platform libs like x86, make sure your device/emulator is not on that platform.

Answer (score 1):

Are you **loading the OpenCV library in a JAVA static statemen**t? If not, put this somewhere in your activity:

```
static { 
   System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); //the name of the .so file, without the 'lib' prefix
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include NDK support on Android studio by making some changes to your local.properties file and your Build.gradle. Here is a video showing in detail how to build NDK application on Android Studio
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fEtrekNcOo

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for the help, now I got it sorted out!

Actually what I did is to follow the instruction from G3M's video at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0fEtrekNcOo to add ndk capability to my project, i.e. adding the following line to my app's local.properties:

```
ndk.dir=D\:\\AndroidSDK\\ndk
```

Then, following Kiran's advice, I went through the steps from [this setup instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/27356635#27356635)

In the end, I was able to make the static call suggested by bonnyz to get the "opencv_java" library:

```
static { 
    System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); //the name of the .so file, without the 'lib' prefix
}
```

Answer (score 0):

after my long research I fixed it with the code given below:

```
sourceSets.main {
    jni.srcDirs = []
    jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
}
```