# Error using OpenCV Android libs in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv

I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267) stack overflow answer to try and get OpenCV android working in Android Studio. I have followed the directions with the following caveats:

- The build tools version in the opencv build.gradle is 19.1.0 instead of 19.0.1
- Instead of looking like the picture provided after a gradle sync, my project structure looks like this:
  [image]
- When I open the module dialog, opencv appears as a model, as well as app

The project builds and autocompletes fine. However, I get the following error when the code that requires OpenCV is called:

```
    java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat:()
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to explicitly load libs with LoadLibrary:

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/System.html