# Opencv initialization in Android studio

Tags: android, opencv, gradle, static

I am using Android studio and opencv 3.0. I tried adding opencv using the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool).

While working with it each packages and classes were imported perfectly without any error, however when I run the app it crashes with the following log.

```
06-29 16:26:38.481      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to get library list
06-29 16:26:38.482      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication E/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ OpenCV error: Cannot load info library for OpenCV
06-29 16:26:38.482      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Library list: ""
06-29 16:26:38.482      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ First attempt to load libs
06-29 16:26:38.482      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to init OpenCV libs
06-29 16:26:38.483      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Trying to load library opencv_java
06-29 16:26:38.483      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ Cannot load library "opencv_java"
06-29 16:26:38.483      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication W/System.err﹕ java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.pak.myapplication-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.pak.myapplication-2/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java.so"
06-29 16:26:38.485      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.loadLibrary(StaticHelper.java:64)
06-29 16:26:38.485      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCVLibs(StaticHelper.java:95)
06-29 16:26:38.485      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.opencv.android.StaticHelper.initOpenCV(StaticHelper.java:39)
06-29 16:26:38.485      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication W/System.err﹕ at org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader.initDebug(OpenCVLoader.java:72)
06-29 16:26:38.486      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication D/OpenCV/StaticHelper﹕ First attempt to load libs fails
06-29 16:26:38.489      559-559/com.example.pak.myapplication I/opencv﹕ opencv initialization unsuccessful
```

I checked the apk and project stucture... it had `libopencv_java3.so` in `main/jniLibs` folder but still no help...

Comment: Check out my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35135495/5611377.  It has screenshots of what should happen when it loads correctly.