# How to import openCV 3.1 in android studio 1.5.1

Tags: opencv, android-studio

I'm following these [steps](https://blog.hig.no/gtl/2015/10/01/android-studio-opencv/), but when I build it has an error:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below steps for using Android OpenCV sdk in Android Studio. This is a simplified version of this([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267)) SO answer.

1. Download latest OpenCV sdk for Android from [OpenCV.org](http://opencv.org/downloads.html) and decompress the zip file.
2. Import OpenCV to Android Studio, From File -> New -> Import Module, choose sdk/java folder in the unzipped opencv archive.
3. Update build.gradle under imported OpenCV module to update 4 fields to match your project build.gradle a) compileSdkVersion b) buildToolsVersion c) minSdkVersion and 4) targetSdkVersion.
4. Add module dependency by Application -> Module Settings, and select the Dependencies tab. Click + icon at bottom, choose Module Dependency and select the imported OpenCV module.

   - For Android Studio v1.2.2, to access to Module Settings : in the project view, right-click the dependent module -> Open Module Settings
5. Copy libs folder under sdk/native to Android Studio under app/src/main.
6. In Android Studio, rename the copied libs directory to jniLibs and we are done.

Step (6) is since Android studio expects native libs in app/src/main/jniLibs instead of older libs folder. For those new to Android OpenCV, don't miss below steps

- include static{ System.loadLibrary("opencv_java"); } (Note: for
  OpenCV version 3 at this step you should instead load the library
  opencv_java3.)
- For step(5), if you ignore any platform libs like x86, make sure your device/emulator is not on that platform.

OpenCV written is in C/C++. Java wrappers are

1. [Android OpenCV SDK](http://opencv.org/platforms/android.html) - OpenCV.org maintained Android Java wrapper. I
   suggest this one.
2. [OpenCV Java](http://opencv.org/opencv-java-api.html) - OpenCV.org maintained auto generated desktop Java wrapper.
3. [JavaCV](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv) - Popular Java wrapper maintained by independent developer(s). Not Android specific. This library might get out of sync with OpenCV newer versions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer I've done this :)

Comment: @LovelyToonZ If it works, you should [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/225842).