# link dll and jar file to android studio

Tags: java, android, opencv

This question might seem too basic but I'm struggling a lot about this stuff, please help me or guide me.

I downloaded `opencv (open source computer vision)` libraries and I want `Android Studio` to be able to use those libraries.

I checked this answer also-[How to use opencv in android studio using gradle build tool?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool/22427267#22427267)
but this answer talks about having `opencv-android-sdk` and nowadays I think `opencv` has not anything like `opencv-android-sdk` , so I couldn't follow that answer.

Now the main point is, what I downloaded and extracted has a folder named java , there is a `opencv-320.jar` file and two folder `x86 and x64`, x64 folder contains `opencv_java320.dll` file. I believe these two files are only files needed to get `opencv` libraries in `Android Studio`. But I don't know how it can be done. Please help me.

Comment: where did you download those files?

Comment: Android doesn't use .dlls.  Dll are windows executable files.  Android is a linux OS.  You need to build .so files (which are the same type of thing, but a different file format).  Also 99% of Android devices are ARM, not x86.  So you need the arm .so files, not the x86 ones.

Answer (score -1):

You should not be using any dll or jar file that is not specifically for Android.

OpenCV has an Android version: http://opencv.org/platforms/android/

Follow the instructions and example there in order to use it.

Comment: You an use almost any jar file in android (the only time you can't is if it uses Java 8 features or java standard library calls not in android.  About 90% of non-GUI jars will work.

Comment: "the only time you can't is if it uses Java 8 features or java standard library calls not in android" or in other words - is specifically for Android.

Comment: Not at all. The vast majority of non-gui libraries will work