# How can I add OpenCV library to my react-native project?

Tags: android, opencv, react-native

I have create a react-native project, I want to do some image processing. I am quite familiar with OpenCV, so I want to use OpenCV library in my project.

I have searched for node module but I can't found it.

So, I tried to implement library with [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22427267/8330122) likn Android Studio.

**1.** I have this structure of project :
[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eVLQ.png)

**2.** I create Native module from react-native tutorial

[Native Module Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZdoAY.png)

**3.** When I run : 
    react-native run-android
I get these errors :

```
:app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\MainApplication.java:15: error: cannot find symbol
import com.opencvproject2.opencvcamera;
                     ^
  symbol:   class opencvcamera
  location: package com.opencvproject2
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:14: error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
import org.opencv.android.BaseLoaderCallback;
                     ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:15: error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase;
                     ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:16: error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
import org.opencv.android.LoaderCallbackInterface;
                     ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:17: error: package org.opencv.android does not exist
import org.opencv.android.OpenCVLoader;
                     ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:18: error: package org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase does not exist
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewFrame;
                                          ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:19: error: package org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase does not exist
import org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2;
                                          ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:20: error: package org.opencv.core does not exist
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
                  ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:21: error: package org.opencv.highgui does not exist
import org.opencv.highgui.Highgui;
                     ^
C:\CETIC\OpencvProject2\android\app\src\main\java\com\opencvproject2\opencvcamera\OpenCVCameraModule.java:37: error: cannot find symbol
   public Mat displayImage(String path){
      ^
  symbol:   class Mat
  location: class OpenCVCameraModule
```

**So my question is** : Am I missing something to include OpenCV library to my React-Native project ?