# Can I run the opencv .class file to the system in which opencv is not installed?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

Let's I have a Java code with opencv & I get a .class file or bytecode after compiling. So can I run that .class file to other system in which the opencv is not installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That really depends how you're building it, you can create what's known as a 'fat' jar or an 'uber' jar which bundles all the dependencies into the same jar file. Are you using Apache Maven or Ant to build your code?

Comment: Thanks for reply.. since I am not that much good in java, I just want to do some image processing in Android studio, in which I am not able to install opencv , but individually in other Java editor I can. Tha's why I want to make it first in Java &  get the .Class file that I want put in Android studio. is it possible?

Comment: hmm I'm not really sure why you can't just add it as a dependency the same way you would anything else. but having done a little research it looks like this is the way to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-android-studio-using-gradle-build-tool