# How to import openCV 4.5 into a gradle java 16 project in intellij idea?

Tags: java, opencv, gradle, intellij-idea

I want to add opencv into my gradle java 16 project using intellij idea.

Is there guide in can follow that creates a sample project.

is there a difference between the android version?

Comment: Please see the related discussion at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767557/how-to-use-opencv-in-using-gradle .

Comment: is there a difference to the android version?